# Dual display with old Ubuntu laptop

Tags: multiple-monitors, laptop, 32-bit

I have an old 32-bit laptop that only has ubuntu and my daily use laptop also running ubuntu(Pop 19.10) I want to use the old laptop as a second monitor to the other one.

> Any help is much appreciated but I would prefer a wireless a solution ( *maybe by bringing them on the same network* )
>
> I have done this with windows using spacedesk but can't find a linux alternative.

Comment: Did you try [x2vnc](http://fredrik.hubbe.net/x2vnc.html)? Is on official repos. Would be like a Spacedesk for Linux.

Comment: @PabloBianchi I did not try this specifically but other solutions that were following the same approach of making a vnc server like https://github.com/fperdigon/Extend2VNC and https://github.com/mrenrich84/vnc_virtual_display_linker . Some were just cloning the display while others just turned out to be too buggy. So, I gave up the idea months ago but thanks to you, I will give it another try tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

for me, I have tried spacedesk.net for free. For primary server is my Windows computer, and a client for Ubuntu 32bit. Officially they don't have the client for Ubuntu, but they made a HTML5 which support chrome or chromium 32bit version 90 in my ubuntu 16.04 32bit.
It works fine but a little bit laggy. Since I use it for comparing two documents or pictures for typo, so it fit my need.

another answer, you may try `synergy` or its open-source version of barrier. but this cannot be installed to my ubuntu 32-bit laptop, just let you know.